# Cómo mostrar una funcion de Models en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Quiero mostrar lo que me devuelve la función get_price.

Dejo el código del models.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name

def get_price(self):
    return self.product.price
```

Dejo el models de product, ya que no funciona al poner `{{ object.get_price }}`

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
price = models.FloatField()
price_offer = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/photos')
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: A que te refieres con mostrar? Puedes ejecutar el metodo `get_price` sin problemas, todo esta bien...

Comment: Como hago para mostrarlo en el template @JulioCesar?

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar en el template lo que retorna el método `get_price`, seria así:

```
{{ object.get_price }}
```

Evidentemente, si el objeto no esta relacionado con una instancia del modelo `Product`, dará error (toma en cuenta esto, ya que la relación tiene `null=True`).

Por otra parte para que entiendas mejor como funciona la representación de plantillas (fuente. [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)):

> Los puntos tienen un significado especial en la representación de
> plantillas. Un punto en el nombre de una variable significa una
> **búsqueda** . Específicamente, cuando el sistema de plantillas encuentra un punto en el nombre de una variable, intenta las
> siguientes búsquedas, en este orden:
>
> - Búsqueda de diccionario. Ejemplo: `foo["bar"]`
> - Búsqueda de atributos. Ejemplo: `foo.bar`
> - Búsqueda de índice de lista. Ejemplo: `foo[bar]`

Y si cualquier "parte" de la variable (`{{ foo }}`) es invocable o *callable*, el sistema de plantillas intentará llamarla (es por eso que no es necesario poner los paréntesis, ademas de que si los pones dara error).

Hay mas ejemplos en la documentación de Django, donde podrás entender mejor como es que funciona. Por otra parte te recomiendo revisar [El lenguaje de plantilla Django: para programadores de Python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#the-django-template-language-for-python-programmers) donde podrás entender a profundidad como funciona el sistema de representación de plantillas, es bastante curioso xD.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No me funciona, porque puede ser? No se muestra nada. Pongo el codigo del models de product.

Comment: Todo funciona bien, y no has mencionado ningún error, así que debería ser que la instancia del modelo `OrderItem` no esta relacionada con ninguna instancia del modelo `Product`, no le encuentro otra explicación...

Comment: El OneToOne de product esta bien?

Comment: Pues si esta bien, si no fuera así, obtuvieras un error. Pero toma en cuenta que tu `OneToOneField` tiene un `null=True`, así que ¿estas seguro que has relacionado una instancia? (intenta poner esto en la shell: `object.product` y dime que te sale...)

Comment: En el shell, deberia importar ambos models? Importando los 2 models, me sale "AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'product'"

Comment: Eso es muy raro, estas seguro que "object" es una instancia del modelo `OrderItem`? (`object = OrderItem.objects.get(...)`?). Por otra parte asegúrate de que `object` no sea un QuerySet...

Comment: Al poner `object = OrderItem.objects.all()` me sale `<QuerySet [<OrderItem: Picadillo Swift>, <OrderItem: Agua Mineral Villavicencio 500ml>]>`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113993/discussion-between-julio-cesar-and-lucas-leone).